# ASP.NET Url Routing Basics

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-routing

I am getting familiar with Url routing and got stuck pretty fast. I am trying to adjust url of one file in root folder, so instead of "http://localhost:55805/Maps.aspx" it shows just "http://localhost:55805/maps". Simple stuff, no parameters etc. I created Global.asax file and added following code.

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            routes.MapPageRoute("maproute", "maps", "~/Maps.aspx");
        }
```

Link I am calling looks like this.

```
<div id="Div6" class="menuitem"><h3><a class="fill-div" href="../Maps.aspx")">Maps</a></h3></div>
```

Does anyone have an idea how should I adjust the code. I experimented with various <% GetRouteUrl... %> commands, but without help. Is is caused by the fact that its not server control? Tried to use hyperlink instead, but didnt help. I am using .NET version 4.5.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways:

1.- Using RouteUrl expresion and HyperLink

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" 
    NavigateUrl="<%$RouteUrl:routename=maproute%>">
   Maps
</asp:HyperLink>
```

2.- Using virtual url and HyperLink

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" 
    NavigateUrl="~/maps">
    Maps
</asp:HyperLink>
```

3.- Using runat server anchor and RouteUrl expression

```
<a class="fill-div" href="<%$RouteUrl:routename=maproute%>" runat="server">Maps</a>
```

4.- Using runat server anchor and virtual url

```
<a class="fill-div" href="~/maps" runat="server">Maps</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to just use `<a class="fill-div" href="/maps">` ?